# How do I reference a div from javascript in pocket ie?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, pocketpc

Hello i'm developing a pocket ie site.
Im runnning pocket PC 2003 SE emulator with pocket ie.

i have a  and want to reference it from javascript.

`getElementById` and `document.getElementsByTagName` don't work.
In an example I saw `document.all[]` and even `xx.id` but all don't work.

Can anyone enlighten me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end it turned out to be..

```
document.[id of the div]
```

So: `<div id="xx"> => document.xx`

Answer (score 1):

You can start from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms838090.aspx) and see the exact support this type of devices have.

Under the Web Development section they referred to [For more information, see Designing Web Sites for Mobile Devices.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa458690.aspx).

From [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa457277.aspx) page your options look grim... :-(